# Using JGraphT to Manage Ordering of Dependent Tasks

Tags: jgrapht

I have a list of tasks that have dependencies between them and I was considering how I could use JGraphT to manage the ordering of the tasks. I would set up the graph as a directed graph and remove vertices as I processed them (or should I mask them?). I could use `TopologicalOrderIterator` if I were only going to execute one task at a time but I'm hoping to parallelize the tasks. I could get `TopologicalOrderIterator` and check `Graphs.vertexHasPredecessors` until I find as many as I want to execute as once but ideally, there would be something like `Graphs.getVerticesWithNoPredecessors`. I see that Netflix provides a utility to get leaf vertices, so I could reverse the graph and use that, but it's probably not worth it. Can anyone point me to a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A topological order may not necessary be what you want. Here's an example why not. Given the following topological ordering of tasks: `[1,2,3,4]`, and the arcs `(1,3)`, `(2,3)`. That is, task `1` needs to be completed before task `3`, similar for `2` and `4`. Let's also assume that task `1` takes a really long time to complete. So we can start processing tasks `1`, and `2` in parallel, but you cannot start `3` before `1` completes. Even though task `2` completes, we cannot start task `4` because task `3` is the next task in our ordering and this task is being blocked by `1`.

Here's what you could do. Create an array `dep[]` which tracks the number of unfulfilled dependencies per task. So `dep[i]==0` means that all dependencies for task `i` have been fulfilled, meaning that we can now perform task `i`. If `dep[i]>0`, we cannot perform task `i` yet. Lets assume that there is a task `j` which needs to be performed prior to task `i`. As soon as we complete task `j`, we can decrement the number of unfulfilled dependencies of task `i`, i.e: `dep[i]=dep[i]-1`. Again, if `dep[i]==0`, we are now ready to process task `i`.
So in short, the algorithm in pseudocode would look like this:

1. Initialize `dep[]` array.
2. Start processing in parallel all tasks `i` with `dep[i]==0`
3. if a task `i` completes, decrement `dep[j]` for all tasks `j` which depend on `i`. If task `j` has `dep[j]==0`, start processing it.

You could certainly use a Directed Graph to model the dependencies. Each time you complete a task, you could simply iterate over the outgoing neighbors (in jgrapht use the successorsOf(vertex) function). The DAG can also simply be used to check feasibility: if the graph contains a cycle, you have a problem in your dependencies. However, if you don't need this heavy machinery, I would simply create a 2-dimensional array where for each task `i` you store the tasks that are dependent on `i`.

The resulting algorithm runs in O(n+m) time, where n is the number of tasks and m the number of arcs (dependencies). So this is very efficient.

Comment: Thanks Joris! This sounds like it would work and would be performant. For my case, I expect < 500 vertices so it may not justify more complexity than simply iterating over entries in TopographicalOrder, checking for Graphs.vertexHasPredecessors==false.

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite Consider 'accepting' the answer if it was helpful and answers your question.

Comment: Well, as I described in my comment response a few years ago your answer was not the direction I was hoping to find.

Comment: Well, as I described in my comment response a few years ago your answer was not the direction I was hoping to find.