# Graph - How to use topological sort to execute dependency tasks

Tags: java, graph-theory, guava, jgrapht

I have a usecase where I have jobs which can have dependencies or be boxes containing other jobs like in autosys.

For e.g JOB_BOX contains JOB1, JOB2 and JOB3 where JOB2 depends on JOB1 and JOB3 depends on nothing.

1. JOB_BOX

   - JOB1
   - JOB2
   - JOB3

boxes can contain box type job as well.
so when someone triggers JOB_BOX the following should occur

1. Start JOB1 and JOB3 parallely
2. Once JOB1 completes start JOB2
3. Mark JOB_BOX complete when all of the jobs are complete.

I am using JgraphT DirectedAcyclicGraph to construct the graph of these jobs but I am not sure how to go about accomplishing this usecase using topological sort.

The topological iterator will give me [JOB1 -> JOB3 -> JOB2 -> JOB_BOX] but I will need to execute JOB1 and JOB3 simultaneously.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DirectedAcyclicGraph<String, DefaultEdge> jobGraph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    jobGraph.addVertex("JOB_BOX");
    jobGraph.addVertex("JOB1");
    jobGraph.addVertex("JOB2");
    jobGraph.addVertex("JOB3");
    //preReqJob -> Job
    jobGraph.addEdge("JOB1", "JOB_BOX");
    jobGraph.addEdge("JOB2", "JOB_BOX");
    jobGraph.addEdge("JOB3", "JOB_BOX");
    jobGraph.addEdge("JOB1", "JOB2");
    TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge> iterator = new TopologicalOrderIterator<>(jobGraph);
    iterator.forEachRemaining(job -> {
        System.out.print(job + " -> ");
    });
}
```

}

o/p for the above:

```
JOB1 -> JOB3 -> JOB2 -> JOB_BOX ->
```

Idea is that I need to go in sequence of executing jobs based on the dependencies but also apply parallelism wherever applicable.

I have thought of an approach

Approach 1:

- I do the topological traversal and then for every jobName that I get
  I check the inDegree of that job i.e if(inDegreeOfJob == 0) then it
  is a candidate of simultaneous execution. that way I get JOB1 and
  JOB3 from the first set of traversal.
- Once JOB1 and JOB3 are complete, I check for subsequent jobs which
  are connecting JOB1 and JOB3 in that case I will get JOB2 alone
  since there is an edge from JOB1 -> JOB2
- once JOB2 is complete, I check for subsequent job which
  is connecting hence I get JOB_BOX and I mark that complete.

any help is appreciated and if there is any resource or any other approach you can point me to that would also be great.

Ref:

[How to do Topological Sort (Dependency Resolution) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372211/how-to-do-topological-sort-dependency-resolution-with-java)

Comment: Since JOB3 depends on nothing, there is something wrong with your input to the 'topological iterator' since it is showing JOB3 depending on job1.  You need to post your input.

Comment: @ravenspoint apologies for the confusion, have added sample code and o/p

Comment: Question seems to be a duplicate of: [Topological sort with detecting vertices that have equal priorities with JGraphT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69745237/topological-sort-with-detecting-vertices-that-have-equal-priorities-with-jgrapht/69758522#69758522)
Also related: [Using JGraphT to Manage Ordering of Dependent Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840485/using-jgrapht-to-manage-ordering-of-dependent-tasks)

Comment: @JorisKinable yes, that answers it. Thank you so much.